# Having trouble connecting to my university's WPA2 secured network with network-manager on Debian

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I've been trying for days now to connect my Debian machine to my university's WPA2 secured eduroam network.

The network's specifications are as follows

- Security Type: WPA2 Enterprise
- Encryption Type: AES
- Authentication Method: PEAP, EAP MSCHAPv2

The network manager I have been attempting to connect with is network-manager.

What happens when I try to connect:
I configure the network settings to meet my university's specification of PEAP and MSCHAPv2, tick the option that says no CA cert is required (none is required), enter my username and password (which I know are correct), and click connect. It attempts to connect, and not even a second later, it drops the process and goes back to connect (successfully) to the UNSECURED network that I also have access to. No error messages, nothing.
Just to clarify, this is not the known bug where it infinitely asks for authentication. It does not do this.

I know that this is not a hardware problem, because I can easily connect to unsecured networks.

More information:

I have tried multiple other network managers, but to no avail.

ConnMan - surprisingly succeeded in connection, but disconnected not 5 minutes later and would not let me reconnect

wicd - refused to connect to anything, even unsecured networks. It either hung on "Obtaining IP Address" in the case of unsecured, or returned the error "bad password" in the case of secured.

I would prefer to stick to network-manager, because I feel that it can work.

I would very much appreciate it if someone were to attempt to help me out here, I have no other resources left at this point. I am on the verge of reinstalling Debian, and will do so if I cannot find an answer.
Thank you.

Comment: There should be error messages available thru dmesg. You should try dmesg -T | grep -E 'wlan0|wifi' `.   If  no messages are found, go to /var/log and issue  grep -nrI 'wlan0|wifi'. This will produce much output, try to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I honestly wasn't expected to see anything until tomorrow. I cannot try this now, but I will tomorrow. Do questions get bumped here?

Comment: nope, no such thing. Just send me a comment, when you have the new info.

Comment: I decided to try your suggestion right now, and the weirdest thing happened. Upon booting into my desktop, I noticed that I was connected to the eduroam network. I could actually access the internet. I just don't understand it. The other weird thing is that that's the only secured network that I can connect to. I cannot connect to the other secured network, which uses the exact same credentials as the eduroam one (they are linked). In fact, I can't connect to the other unsecured networks anymore either. I have no clue what is going on here.

Comment: When in doubt, you may restart your wifi: `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0`, and see whether that helps. A reboot may also be in order.

Comment: And, BTW, I too have unsavory experiences with eduroam, for reasons I never completely elucidated.

Comment: I have rebooted a few times, I just connect to the eduroam network immediately. Bash tells me that it cannot find ifdown or ifup.

Comment: I just tried to disconnect from eduroam. When I did, it and all other WiFi networks disappeared completely. Only after I rebooted did they appear after automatically connecting to the eduroam network.

Comment: pls see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are several components involved in a wifi connection, and at this point it is not clear which one is responsible for this strange behaviour, given also that you have not looked at the error messages.

The next time you experience the same problem (disconnection from eduroam, impossibility to detect any other wifi network), proceed as follows:

1. Issue the commands:

   ```
             sudo ifdown wlan0
             sudo ifup wlan0
   ```

   and now try to see whether the wifi works again;
2. if it does not, issue the commands:

   ```
            sudo service networking stop
            sudo service networking start
   ```

   and now try to see whether the wifi works again;
3. if it does not, issue the commands

   ```
           sudo service network-manager stop
           sudo service network-manager start
   ```

   and try to see whether the wifi works again.

If it does not, you will have to search amidst the error messages, as I stated in my comment, no way to wiggle your way out of this.